# HTML radio input with (required) text option for "other"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have a set of radio inputs with an option "other" that has a text field. My question is how I make the text field required when the other option is selected.

The code I came up with so far::

```
<form method="POST" action="testPage.php">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">Option 3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="">Other 
  <input type="text" name="othertext" onchange="changeradioother()">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>

  function changeradioother(){
  var other= document.getElementById("other");
  other.value=document.getElementById("inputother").value;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling a function `when other radio button is clicked` to set `input field to required` :

```html
<script>

function changeradioother(){
   var other= document.getElementById("other");
   other.value=document.getElementById("inputother").value;
   }
function setRequired(){

 document.getElementById("inputother").required=true;
}

function removeRequired(){
if(document.getElementById("inputother").required == true){
 document.getElementById("inputother").required=false;
}
}
</script>

<form method="POST" action="testPage.php">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" onclick="removeRequired();">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" onclick="removeRequired();">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3" onclick="removeRequired();">Option 3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="" onclick="setRequired();" id="other">Other 
  <input id="inputother" type="text" name="othertext" onchange="changeradioother()">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: When you first click other, and then back to any other option, it still field is still required.

Comment: @Ivar good point even  Op never asked to change it to normal, but i'll change it.Thanks.

Comment: It worked! I liked this one because it doesnt open an alert box. Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

There are many diff ways to this one is here 
 give id to your radio box which is other and give id to text box.

```js
 function changeradioother(){
 
  if(document.getElementById("Other").checked ) {
     if(document.getElementById("inputtext").value == ''){
         alert('input required');
     }
  }
     return false
  }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="testPage.php" onsubmit="return changeradioother()">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">Option 3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="" id="Other">Other 
  <input type="text" name="othertext" id="inputtext" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: do you think this is javascript.it is jquery

Comment: no i thing it's jquery code inside the javascript function

Comment: see the Op tags .I simply meant people can downvote your answer so change it to javascript. or suggest your answer saying `jquery`.

Comment: sorry for that, i will make correct it , thanks for ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that.
Going through all radio button to check which was clicked.

By the way, you did not put an `id` to the radio button `Other`.

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='option']");

for(var i = 0;i< radio.length;i++){
  radio[i].onclick = function(){
    if(this.id == "other"){
      document.getElementById('otherText').setAttribute("required", true);
    }else{
      document.getElementById('otherText').removeAttribute("required");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="testPage.php">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">Option 3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="other">Other 
  <input type="text" name="othertext" id="otherText">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```